# How to copy cleat angle on the same shoe?

Tags: shoes, cleat

I have a triathlon coming up this weekend so I need the old angle of the cleat on my new shoes as the old shoe is completely damaged. How can I get the old angle of the cleat on the new shoe with a new cleat?
The northwave Sonic 2 SRS is very comfortable that's why I bought the shoes again but cannot find a way to do the cleat thing.
Please help me as soon as possible.

[image: As you can see that I bought the same shoe because I liked it, it is comfortable because it is affordable.]

Comment: I'm wondering about a template made using a photocopier or scanner on the old shoe. Clear plastic in began to protect the glass

Comment: Did you know you changed the amount of free float from the maximum available (SH11- yellow)  to zero float (SH10 - red). This arguably could also have a dramatic effect as well and there is no evidence that a fixed cleat (i.e., no free float) provides any performance advantages, if anything it can lead to repetitive stress injuries. I would also advise against such a big change just before a race.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not using SPD pedals anymore but I would try following to transfer cleat position to new shoes.

I remembered that I've read somewhere that some shoe manufacturers have some kind of paper pattern to mark position of old cleats and use that pattern to adjust position for new cleats. Since I guess your shoe size iz the same for new pair, making this kind of paper pattern and marking where cleat starts/ends would be rather easy. In order to increase precission you can combine this with measuring it with ruler.

Added: There are also products like Ergon TP1 Pedal Cleat Tool but I guess it's rather expensive for just one time use.